# File Creating with read permission for root user alone

Tags: filesystems

I have two different servers built in the same way. but in one server a file is creating with read, write permissions alone for root while the other is with read to all

Server 1: -rw-r-----
Server 2: -rw-r--r--

Can u plz suggest where to check and how to overcome this.

I have checked the Umask values & getfacl commands for cross-validating permissions.

Comment: Any hint on what kind of file? Some runtime files never change their permissions again, so if you once started a service manually on one of the servers, it might have different permissions. Also, it sounds like you re-set the perms and then they changed again?

Comment: for restarting a server we have created a service command which performs multiple things ..same service command is created in both the servers. But the file its creating is having different permissions in different servers.